# Nullify the value binding on IntegerUpDown from spinner

Tags: c#, wpf, spinner, wpftoolkit, integerupdown

Is it possible to set the `Minimum` value of the `IntegerUpDown` (or any `UpDownBase`) to `null`?

The way I would like the control to operate is:

- Initialize as `null`
- Start at `0` if the user increments the spinner
- Return to `null` if the user decrements from `0`

I tried various combinations of setting `IntegerUpDown.Minimum` and `IntegerUpDown.DefaultValue`, but the setter on the property binding seems to re-invoke with the previous value after nullifying (can update with explanation if warranted).

Answer (score 0):

You can define nullable integer (or other variables that doesn't have the null option by default) like this:

```
int? IntegerUpDown = null;
if (IntegerUpDown.HasValue)
{
    int NewInt = IntegerUpDown.Value;
}
```

Comment: I guess @reasra is talking about a [WpfToolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) control...

Comment: Well, this is the basics of setting a variable as nullable, he/she should do the rest :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the value bound to a `int?`. I would simply like the user interface to set the value to `null` with the `IntegerUpDown`'s spinner.